# Is a static variable shared across all instance?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

In a public class, I have a private static Dictionary. Since the Dictionary is static, does it mean that it is shared across all the other instance of the same object (see example below).

```
public class Tax
{
    private static Dictionary<string, double> TaxBrakets = new Dictionary<string, double>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "Individual",   0.18 },
        { "Business",     0.20 },
        { "Other",        0.22 },
    };

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double ComputeTax(string type, double d)
    {
        return d * TaxBrakets[this.Type];
    }
}
```

Is that acceptable to use a Dictionary in that way (as static variable)?

Comment: You should consider not using `string` as your type. Maybe an `enum` and an array would be better than a `string` and a `Dictionary`?

Comment: And if this is real-life code, you should use `decimal` and not `double` for currency. Floating-points have can have weird behavior and numbers like `17.9999999...`. I'm sure there is a question on this site which explains it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your static variable `TaxBrakets` is not associated with an instance. `this.TaxBrakets` would not compile.  All occurrences of `TaxBrakets` will refer to the same dictionary.  In general, it's totally acceptable to use static dictionaries.  This particular use seems a little funny though, but I'd need to see more code to suggest any changes.

Comment: The scope will resolve itself to the class rather than the instance, so `TaxBrackets` alone actually will compile (but as you pointed out, `this.TaxBrackets` will not).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a static variable exists only once in your entire program, I think it will behave the way you expect.

Whether that's the right solution to your accounting problem is debatable, IANAA but my understanding is that tax brackets (note: the correct spelling of "brackets" has a `c`) equate income levels to marginal tax rates, knowing the type of the entity is not by itself sufficient to determine the tax rate.

Comment: Exists only once per `AppDomain` to be precise.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: That's a true statement, but I hardly think that the OP is likely to be using multiple AppDomains.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that static member will be shared by all instances. (Visual Basic actually makes this explicit by using the [`Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx) keyword for static members, rather than [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).)

It's perfectly acceptable to use a dictionary in that way, with one caveat: if your code is multithreaded then you must ensure that access to the static member is thread-safe. (Of course, this applies to any members that might be accessed concurrently, not just statics.)

Not directly related to the question, but you should probably use [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), rather than [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx), for anything related to monetary values or financial calculations.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it will be shared and **yes** that should be fine, it will be thread-safe as well as no updating. I would just add `readonly` to the declartion:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, double> TaxBrakets = new Dictionary<string, double>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "Individual",   0.18 },
        { "Business",     0.20 },
        { "Other",        0.22 },
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

A static property isn't really *shared* by instances, per se, but your usage of it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, static indicates that it is a single variable within the class Tax.

You would need to access it like

```
return d * Tax.TaxBrackets[this.Type]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: You don't have to specify the class name when you are using the static member from within the class.

Comment: The `Tax.` prefix is not needed, static members can be found by unqualified name lookup when used within other members of the same class (and descendants).

Comment: Yes I know that it is not necessary, however it does help to alleviate some confusion when others come in to maintain your code and need to find what that variable is.  Especially in things like Java where you can do static imports, then it becomes increasingly difficult to keep track of where a static member was imported from.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, if it were not hidden by `private`, then it would be available even without any instance.

For example:

```
public class X
{
    public static String y = "abc";
}

// other code, even without instances of X alive:
Console.WriteLine(X.y);
```

Comment: Even being private it's accessible without an instance, for example from inner instance classes.

Comment: Very true. I intentionally ignored the use of Reflection, but the inner class example had slipped my mind.